# web scraping by BeautifulSoup python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** product's of online store by BeautifulSoup but i have a problem, There is only one product i can **scrape**! , but i want to **scrape** all product's.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get('https://www.digikala.com/search/category-wearable-gadget/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find_all('div', class_='c-product-box__content')
first_watch = result[0]
first_name = first_watch.a.text
first_rate = first_watch.find(class_='c-product-box__rate-comparision--rate-people')
first_price = first_watch.find(class_='c-price__value-wrapper')
first_rate = first_rate.text
first_price = first_price.text
```

As soon as I use `first_watch = result` and use `find_all`  showing this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "C:/Users/Oogway/PycharmProjects/web_scraping1/web_s.py", line 8, in
>  first_name = first_watch.a.text File
> "C:\Users\Oogway.virtualenvs\web_scraping1\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py",
> line 2160, in__getattr__ raise AttributeError( AttributeError:
> ResultSet object has no attribute 'a'. You're probably treating a list
> of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you
> meant to call find()?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get('https://www.digikala.com/search/category-wearable-gadget/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find_all('div', class_='c-product-box__content')
first_watch = result
first_name = first_watch.a.text
first_rate = first_watch.find_all(class_='c-product-box__rate-comparision--rate-people')
first_price = first_watch.find_all(class_='c-price__value-wrapper')
first_rate = first_rate.text
first_price = first_price.text
```

Comment: FYI It’s scrape not scrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate the `result` object.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get('https://www.digikala.com/search/category-wearable-gadget/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find_all('div', class_='c-product-box__content')
for itm in result:
    print(itm.a.text)
```

`find_all` method will return all the `div` with class `c-product-box__content`.